# There is an items not appearing in my website

Tags: php, html, css

I have a  problem in my website,

It's working well in my xampp **localhost **but when I upload it to the host in specific page called **rate.php**
only **half** of the page appearing

When I upload the website to web host:
[image: The missing objects]

When I use localhost (XAMPP):
[image: The full page]

**Ignore** Non-English texts

There is a comment called  on it

```php
<?php
$current_page = 'doctors';
require('include/functions.php');
require('themes/header.php');

$id = $_GET['id'];
$query = "SELECT * FROM doctors WHERE id=$id";
$results = $connect->query($query);

while ($row = $results->fetch_assoc()) {
    $doctor_name = $row['fullname'];
    $avatar = $row['avatar'];
}
?>
```

```html
<div class="row gx-3">

<div style="transform: scale(0.97);" class="admin_form col-xl-3 col-lg-4 col-md-12 col-sm-12 col-xs-12" style="">

<div class="container">

<img src="<?php echo $avatar;?>" class="image-preview" style="object-fit: cover; width: 100%; height: 270px; margin-top: 17px;"></img>
<br><br><br>
<span style="color: #ff8c00; font-size: 25px; font-weight: bold;"><?php echo $doctor_name;?></span>
<br><br><br>

<span style="color: #000; font-weight: bold; float: right;">متوسط تقييمات الشرح</span>
<span style="color: #ff8c00; font-weight: bold; float: left;">
<!-- THE LAST WORD APPEARING EVEN IN INSPECTOR ^  -->
<?php
$query = "SELECT AVG(explain_rate) AS avg_explain_rate, AVG(marks_rate) AS avg_marks_rate 
FROM rates WHERE doctor_id = '$id'";

// Execute the SQL query
$result = mysqli_query($connect, $query);

// Check if the query executed successfully
if ($result) {
// Fetch the result row
$row = mysqli_fetch_assoc($result);

$avg_explain_rate = $row['avg_explain_rate'];
$avg_explain_rate = number_format($row['avg_explain_rate'], 2); // Format to two decimal places
echo $avg_explain_rate;
}
?>

</span>
```

I tried to Inspect the page and to double-check my $query sql connection.

Comment: Are you sure the query is returning something? Are u doing something if this code is returning false `if ($result){}else{}` ?

Comment: You are at risk of [SQL Injection](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/SQL_injection). Please research "parameterized queries"

Comment: Is this a PHP problem or a CSS problem? What have you tried to resolve it? Where are you stuck?

Comment: Check your server's PHP error log for errors

Comment: **Warning:** Your code is vulnerable to SQL Injection attacks. You should use parameterised queries and prepared statements to help prevent attackers from compromising your database by using malicious input values. http://bobby-tables.com gives an explanation of the risks, as well as some examples of how to write your queries safely using PHP / mysqli. **Never** insert unparameterised data directly into your SQL. The way your code is written now, someone could easily steal, incorrectly change, or even delete your data.  This code should not be anywhere near a public server!!

Comment: https://phpdelusions.net/mysqli also contains good examples of writing safe SQL using mysqli. See also the [mysqli documentation](https://www.php.net/manual/en/mysqli.quickstart.prepared-statements.php) and this: [How can I prevent SQL injection in PHP?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60174/how-can-i-prevent-sql-injection-in-php) . Parameterising your queries will also greatly reduce the risk of accidental syntax errors as a result of un-escaped or incorrectly quoted input values. If you learnt your current technique from a tutorial or book, please don't use that resource again.

Comment: I know that it’s vulnerable and I’ll fix that later and thanks to tell me

Comment: Actually I don't know if it’s from php or css because it’s working without any problem in my localhost

Comment: Then please start checking that. It's not that hard to check whether the generated markup is the same or not (ruling out that PHP is to blame)

Comment: But any object below my php code is hidden

Comment: @OsmanSalih Use DevTools to see what's actually in the DOM. That way you'll be able to tell if it's being hidden by CSS.

Comment: `Actually I don't know`...well then have you tried to do some debugging, or checking for errors, as we've mentioned? "I don't know" isn't a problem we can help you with - you need to do some meaningful investigation and then report back with concrete information about what is happening

Comment: `I know that it’s vulnerable`...then a) why on earth did you put it on a public website?? And b) why did you write it that way in the first place?

Comment: A) because nobody know the website link to attack it.

Comment: B) because it's easier, I'll change it later

Comment: `because nobody know the website link to attack it`...that won't last long. Security by obscurity is not security!! `because it's easier`...it really isn't. Particularly in recent PHP versions, executing a parameterised query with mysqli [is trivial](https://phpdelusions.net/mysqli#exequte_query). And as well as making it safer it also makes your code more reliable and less prone to  accidental syntax errors...which in turn should make it easier to test. So I don't think your point stands up, particularly.